# Could 2D spacetime be seen as an embedded manifold?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

In a chart of a 2-dimensional spacetime manifold, we can write the rule giving separation between two points as:

$$ ds^2 = - dt^2 + dx^2.$$

Could we use this to imagine how space time looks like a surface embedded in $\mathbb{R^3}$?

I am asking because suppose you had a sphere, we could write a metric as:

$$ds^2 = d \theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta d \phi^2$$

We can think of this as telling us how to convert displacements in the $\theta-\phi$ plane to the corresponding displacements on the surface (on sphere). If we integrate arc length of a curve on the sphere using the metric, we would physically find the length measured by keeping a piece of rope (such that it's taut) at the physical points corresponding to final and initial parameter points of the integration.

The idea I want to emphasize here is, is there such a similar 3D shape for which integrating the metric between two spacetime points could be done physically by measuring through a rope construction as said above?

Comment: I don't understand how you think a rope could measure the *negative* values that the Minkowksian $\mathrm{d}s^2$ can have - can you be more specific how this is supposed to work?

Comment: I misspoke a bit, my idea was something analogous to the rope construction rather than ltierally it. Basically the main concern was whether you could fit space time as an emebbeded surface into R^3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean "embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ *with a Euclidean metric*", then the answer is no.

Suppose that such an embedding exists.  Consider the neighborhood of a point $P$ on the submanifold.  For all infinitesimal displacements in a neighborhood of a point in Euclidean space, we have $ds^2 \geq 0$, with equality holding only if $dx^\mu = 0$.  In other words, all nearby points are a positive "distance squared" from $P$.

But this is not true of Minkowski space.  For any point $P$ in Minkowski space, there exist infinitesimal displacements $dx^\mu \neq 0$ for which $ds^2$ is positive, zero, or negative.  The displacements with $ds^2 = 0$ or $ds^2 < 0$ cannot correspond to displacements in a Euclidean space, and so we cannot embed a 2-D manifold in a Euclidean space in such a way that the induced metric is the Minkowski metric.

Comment: @Aplateofmomos:  Yeah, I was playing a bit fast & loose with "points" vs. "infinitesimal displacements".  Hopefully it's clearer now.